# Powershell - get name and mobile from group with more than 5000 members

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I need to extract the name and mobile of all users in an AD group that consists of more than 5000 members.

When I previously did this I only had to extract the name, and this code solved my problem

```
Get-ADGroup 'xxx' -Properties Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member | Sort
Get-ADGroup "xxx" -Properties Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member | Get-ADObject | Select Name | Sort Name
((Get-ADGroup "xxx" -Properties member).member).count
Get-ADGroup "xxx" -Properties Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member | Get-ADObject | Select Name | Sort Name  | Export-Csv C:\temp\exportmembers.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Since groups don't contain the property "mobile" I'm unsure how to go about this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all group members directly using `Get-ADGroupMember`, even with subgroups

```
get-adgroup 'xxxx' |Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
  get-aduser -Properties name,mobile |sort name |select name,mobile |
  Export-Csv C:\temp\exportmembers.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

For the +5000 member issue, just add the property to `Get-AdObject` and `Select-Object`

```
Get-ADGroup "xxx" -Properties Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member | 
  Get-ADObject -Properties mobile | Select Name,mobile | Sort Name  | 
  Export-Csv C:\temp\exportmembers.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but because there's more than 5000 members in the group I get an error saying "Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded".

When I googled I found that the cap is 5000 members for ADGroupMember, which is why I  included that in the OP.

Any chance you know how to get around this?

Comment: @Lars see my edit

Comment: Thank you so much!